# how to center the constraint layout and add padding

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I use Recyclerview , as you can see its left aligned and there is [no margin before the first card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvyOs.png) , and no bottom margin before the last card ([last card button not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un7Af.png)), how can I fix that? I added padding on the card but it didn't work with me 
I also added margins on the constraint layout but the first card always stuck in the top.

XML code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/design_default_color_surface"
app:layout_constraintHeight_max="wrap"
app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap">

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Media -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconfinder_artboard_1_1790655" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="title"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="secondary_text"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/readMore"
            style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:text="Read More" />


    </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Recyclerview XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AllBooksRecycler">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="393dp"
    android:layout_height="717dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post XML of the layout which contains the recyclerview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RecyclerView tag, set both `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `match_parent` instead of hardcoding them.

Remove these two lines from the item layout:

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_max="wrap"
app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't fix max height and width of container remove that `app:layout_constraintHeight_max="wrap"` and `app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"` Try this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/design_default_color_surface">

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Media -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconfinder_artboard_1_1790655" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="title"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="secondary_text"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/readMore"
            style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:text="Read More" />


    </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

For top and bottom first and last item you should using ItemDecoration (this is kotlin code)

```
class SpacingItemDecoration(context: Context) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    // define your dimens you want in dimes.xml
    private val spacing = context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.your_dimen)

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        outRect.top = spacing
        if (position.inc() == parent.adapter!!.itemCount) {
            outRect.bottom = spacing
        }
    }
}
```

Add it when you init `RecyclerView`

```
recycler_view.addItemDecoration(SpacingItemDecoration(context))
```

Comment: now each card take the whole screen, how can I make it come after each other?

Comment: ah this is layout in holder right? should change layout_height to wrap_content, I will edit answer

Comment: yes, when I changed layout_height to wrap_content I had the same problem in my question

Comment: did you still make layout_width match_parent?

Comment: yes    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: is the card in the center?

Comment: So now you only need top and bottom margin right? You should using ItemDecoration instead of fix android:layout_marginTop="32dp"